# OAuth SignInManager Result Failed

Tags: c#, google-oauth, owin

I am new to OAuth authentication currently i am trying to connect through google account. When i try to connect with the gmail, following response occurs.

[image]

after failure info shown on web page.

[image]

What am doing wrong?

Comment: @Stivan Kindly change one of the picture both pictures get same

Comment: for starters thats not oauth or gmail thats just associating your google account with another email account.  its not even Google signin.   Nor does it show any signs of C#.   Welcome to please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it my help you with your future questions.